# Find center and radius of circle with n# of equally spaced points

Tags: circles

Say there is a point P, with coordinates $(x_1,y_1)$, and there is a circle that passes through this point, and the origin.  There are n# of equally spaced points that lie on the circle leading from the origin up to point P.  The first point MUST lie on the x axis.

[image]

I am trying to figure out how to solve for the center and radius of a circle, this is in terms of $n$, $x_1$, and $y_1$! Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: $C$ must lies on the bisector of $OP$. Value of $n$ tells you the angle between $CP$ and $OP$. Intersection of these two lines gives you $C$.

Comment: By cross product find center angle OCP. Divide by 2n getting $ \alpha = arctan( xO/yO)$

Comment: ^Not sure what you mean by "by cross product find center angle OCP". Could you be more specific?